# Show and hide button in Odoo kanban view

Tags: python, odoo

Can you please tell me who to triggers the events in kanban view with the button-like show and hide-on function call?

Answer (score 0):

for this you may need to use odoo javascript to complete such functionality, kindly refer to this documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/javascript_reference.html

If this is not enough, you can always open base addons code and try to understand the way javascript works in them